# Is Cassandra suitable for a system that requires frequent queries (reads/writes)?

Tags: database, nosql, scalability, cassandra, key-value-store

I'm developing a web application that requires a lot of users to be in the same "universe", where a lot of frequent queries will happen:

- frequent lookups of clients that are in a certain box area (between X1, X2, Y1 and Y2)
- frequent position updates by clients
- frequent chat messages by clients
- frequent status updates by clients
- frequent connections and disconnections of new and old clients

I believe my nodes can have enough memory for all currently online users to be in RAM. This is why I originally considered Redis. However, I decided Redis is not applicable here because:

- it has a single point of failure (one master server)
- only the master server can write, if one has 40 nodes then 39 slaves would have to make the one master write each and every entry

Cassandra seems to solve these issues.

**However, is Cassandra also suitable for my frequent queries?**

Comment: Would be useful to say what "frequent" means. Tens of updates a second, or thousands?

Comment: @Malcolm, per client, per node or for the entire cluster?

Comment: For each of the types of update, how often do they occur across your system? The per client & node values depend on your setup assumptions.

Comment: @Malcolm, does that not depend on the amount of users there are active?

Comment: Of course it does - but what are you designing for? Every system will fail at some load level - but you need some parameters otherwise you can't see whether the design will work or not

Comment: @Malcolm, the idea was to "simply add more nodes" when the system "fails at some load level". This is my objective. I would like every user to on average perform a request once every two seconds, with 25.000 simultaneous users that means 12.500 requests a second. I realize this is probably not going to happen, but if it's possible in theory, I would like to work it out in practice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3296/discussion-between-malcolm-box-and-tom)

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra optimises writes over reads (reads are expensive compared to writes), but it can still sustain high read and write throughput simultaneously.

With the right column family structures you should be able to do what you want at high frequencies, depending on how big your cluster is.

Personally I'd use Redis for caching most of the information, and only read from Cassandra on cache miss.

Comment: Twitter and Facebook use Casandra. Do you know if they use it for looking up tweets etc. too, or do they use a different technique such as combining it with redis? The redis combination seems very complex to me.

Comment: I don't work for either, so can't say for sure, but I'd be amazed if they use it without caches in front. Really that's all Redis is - a memory cache with some nice datastructures.

Comment: how can you use redis as a memory cache for a scalable system when redis can only have one master that writes? Since slaves cannot write, all changes in the cassandra database have to be written to redis by the redis master. Now we are back to one point of failure as well as a non-scaling system. Am I not following you here?

Comment: Because a single redis node will scale far higher than your site. And if (or when) you exhaust it, just shard the data sets. As for failure - keep a slave node as hot standby and promote to master, or just fire up a new master node. If you don't like redis as the cache then memcache will scale indefinitely

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra is definitely a superb solution for handling writes but if you can tell your read load then definitely you can expect a precise answer but generally reads are also good as long as you have enough RAM.

The user case you described seems to include many joins..

Do you have enough reasons to adopt NoSQL solution right from the developmental stage? Because Cassandra is basically a solution for setups which require high scalability BUT at the expense of de-normalization and sacrificing Joins to a good extent. In other words you need higher disk space but low CPU.

Or have you finalized your database design and apparent scheme (though Cassandra is not schema bound) which fulfills all of your query especially read query requirements? (its v.imp)

Comment: "as long as you have enough RAM." how does this compare to using something like redis or memcache together with Cassandra?